# Don't Select For NA Values

Tags: r, select, boolean, conditional-statements

This is a minor nuisance in R that I'm looking to see if there is possibly some default case for.

I create the following vector:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, NA)
```

I now want to select from `x`, only values equal to 1. I do as such:

```
x2 <- x[x == 1]
```

Now, when you see what's in `x2` it has the values:

```
> x2
[1]  1  1 NA
```

It seems that R defaults to include NA values regardless of the condition. I would like it so that R by default excludes NA values from conditions (as it is true that `NA` does not satisfy the condition `x == 1`).

I'm aware of the `complete.cases` function, used as such:

```
x2 <- x[complete.cases(x == 1)]
```

The desired output would be the result of the `complete.cases` method as such:

[REMOVED CAUSE I MESSED THIS UP]

Which solves my problem, but I am curious to see if there is a setting in `options` or something like that where I can default R to not include NAs in a boolean condition.

I would like to see if there is a way to set are so that `x2 <- x[x == 1]` results in the same as `x2 <- x[complete.cases(x == 1)]`. Currently the difference is that the non-complete.cases (normal) method allows NAs through and I would like that to not be the case.

---

Hey, sorry, I realized I messed up my output with `complete.cases` as many of you have said, I essentially want to see if I can make this:

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 1, NA)
> x2 <- x[x == 1 & !is.na(x)]
> x2
[1] 1 1
```

Work with just this: `x2 <- x[x == 1]`. Can I make it so that R *automatically* ignores NAs. I could create a function to do this, but wanted to see if there is something built in R for single conditions that ignore NAs.

Comment: What is your desired output?  Without that, I don't think an exact answer can be given.

Comment: Sorry, thought I made that clear. Making an edit.

Comment: I could do that, but that's an extra condition. But is there a way to tell R that I ONLY want such cases where `x == 1` and NOT allow NAs to get through? Again, it's kind of an anal question as I can wrap it in `complete.cases`, but I find it tedious to do so.

Comment: Stating the obvious here, but: you could put an arbitrary value and still get your desired output: `x[complete.cases(x == 999)]` or even `x[complete.cases(x == "gadzooks")]`. That is, your desired output is 1-to-1 with is.na.

Comment: `x2 <- x[!is.na(x) & x == 1]`?

Comment: do you really want `x[complete.cases(x == 1)]` since that returns a 2.. or `x[x %in% 1]` ? or even `na.omit(x)` if you do want the 2

Comment: And yeah, I messed up with `complete.cases` that was not the output I wanted. I fixed it, but the `which` method posted below is satisfactory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need which?

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 1, NA)
> x[which(x==1)]
[1] 1 1
```

To explain, `which(x==1)` will give you the locations in your vector `x` that matches the test, `x==1`. You use this result to subset `x`, giving the output.

```
> which(x==1)
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: A similar option: `x[ x %in% 1 ]`

Comment: Not totally what I was looking for, but `which` seems like an effective one line wrapper for this, which ;), is good enough. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Filter`:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, NA)
isEqualOne<- function(x) x == 1
x |> Filter(f = isEqualOne)
#[1] 1 1
```

Or, in one line, you can call an anonymous function:

```
Filter(\(n) n == 1,x)
```

This work cause the documentation of `?Filter` says:

> Filter [...] returns the subset of x for which this gives true. Note that possible NA values are currently always taken as false

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the functional value of returning a vector which contains the elements equal to 1, because all these elements will be 1.  Rather, in production you most likely would be returning a boolean vector, where `TRUE` means a value matches and `FALSE` means a value does not match.

If you want `NA` values to show up as being `FALSE` for not matching, then you can make the comparison and simply replace these `NA` values with false:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, NA)
x2 <- x == 1
x2[is.na(x2)] <- FALSE
> x2
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, but you're essentially doing in two lines which you could do in one. Just trying to condense my code and make it simpler to write.

Comment: Fair enough.  Treating `NA` as `FALSE` or `TRUE` might cause logical problems depending on the type of problem you're working with.